# "Ну(,) а если вы так указываете на ошибку, то извиняюсь." Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Ну а если вы так указываете на ошибку, то извиняюсь.*

Нужна ли запятая после "ну"?

Answer (score 3):

> "Нужна ли запятая после "ну"?

Не нужна. В этом предложении ***"ну"*** -- [***частица***, служит для усиления последующего высказывания. **Интонационно (и знаками препинания) не отделяется от последующих слов.**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501)

[***Ну*** а если любит, то и сам приедет, и гостей привезет.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501)

===============================

> Это частица "ну а если".

Нет, не так. Разбираемое предложение -- **сложное**, ***[е́сли..., то](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274913)*** в нём -- **союз**.

Comment: Слава, см. словарь Ефремовой. Ефремова утверждает, что частица. Если рассматривать ну в качестве частицы при союзе "если", то какое значение оно имеет? Грамота говорит, что частица "ну'' имеет значение ''так'' и так'', ''допустим''. Вряд ли можно сказать, что частица ''ну" имеет такое значение здесь.

Comment: Серж, предложение-то -- **сложноподчинённое!** Чем соединяются части таких предложений?

Comment: Слава, я с вами согласен. Но это мнение Ефремовой, у которой кстати два варианта представлены: ну а - частица, ну а если - частица.

Comment: А у Ефремовой "ну а если" не в вопросе ли?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна, поскольку, *ну а если* - это частица.

Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

Comment: Интересно.  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501